# HUAWEI Themes for Smartwatch using Themestudio 11.05.300

Tags: huawei-mobile-services, huawei-developers

I have ThemeStudio 11.05.300. It supports HWT version 2.8.1.
Can the HWT version 2.8.1 still be used only in gt2 pro?

i want make sure version 2.8 only with gt2 pro, it can not be available gt2 or others right?

Answer (score 0):

GT Pro and GS Pro both are available with 2.1.X to 2.8.X version.

Please check below reference link for detailed information:

https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/distribution/content/summary-0000001096442047

[image]